# Sybase - Conditional Join on Columns based on value of one column

Tags: t-sql, join, conditional-statements, sybase

I have a situation where I would require to do a conditional join based on the value of the columns on one of the tables.

`table_a ta 


    join table_b tb on

    case 

     when ta.column_1 = 1 then ta.column_2 = tb.column_2 

     when ta.column_1 = 2 then ta.column_2 = tb.column_2 and ta.column_3 = tb.column_3

     when ta.column_1 = 3 then ta.column_2 = tb.column_2 and ta.column_3 = tb.column_3 and ta.column_4 = tb.column_4 

    end`

Please advise how I should go about it?

Tried searching and got some options to use a `left join` but I am not sure how to do it. :(

Please advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think it's all can be formulated as single boelean expression

```
...
join table_b tb on 
(ta.column_1 = 1 and ta.column_2 = tb.column_2) or
(ta.column_1 = 2 and ta.column_2 = tb.column_2 and ta.column_3 = tb.column_3)
...
```

Comment: Very elegant solution. Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `left joins` and put the `case expression` when selecting the columns:

```
select
    case when ta.column_1 = 1 then b1.column
    case when ta.column_1 = 2 then b2.column
    case when ta.column_1 = 3 then b3.column
    end
from table_a ta
left join table_b b1 on ta.column_2 = tb.column_2
left join table_b b2 on ta.column_2 = tb.column_2 and ta.column_3 = tb.column_3 
left join table_b b3 on ta.column_2 = tb.column_2 and ta.column_3 = tb.column_3 and ta.column_4 = tb.column_4
```

Answer (score 0):

Try a union

```
select * from tbla ta, tblb tb
where ta.column_1 = 1
  and ta.column_2 = tb.column_2
union
select * from tbla ta, tblb tb
where ta.column_1 = 2
  and ta.column_2 = tb.column_2
  and ta.column_3 = tb.column_3
union
select * from tbla ta, tblb tb
where ta.column_1 = 3
  and ta.column_2 = tb.column_2
  and ta.column_3 = tb.column_3
  and ta.column_4 = tb.column_4
```

tada